# How do I do pattern match on an infinite stream in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, stream, match, infinite

I'm not sure if this is even possible.
Suppose I have an infinite incoming stream of characters, and I want to find the first match of a certain string (say, a short word). Is it possible to implement it using Java's stream API?

The only obvious algorithm I can think of is that if the first charater of the word is encountered in the stream, check the next character from the stream, and if it equals the next charater of the word, check the 3rd character. Because the word or pattern only has a few charaters, this algorithm sounds plausible. But I find it very difficult to implement with the stream API. I was wondering if it's possible to achieve this.It might be theoretically impossible.

Some experts suggest that I should use InputStream. Maybe I didn't explain my intention clearly. What I'm thinking is to create an infinite stream of random charactors and see when I can encounter the word that I specify. It's like an experiment. java.util.stream api is very handy to produce a stream of infinite random charactors, but seems difficult to do the matching. InputStream seems even more impractical. It only accepts inputs from files, urls and user console.Infinity is not possible. What should I do? Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: No, you should not use the java stream api (java.util.stream) for that, the stream you should instead focus on are the ones related to [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and company. There you can read the data as it comes in and stop whenever you hit a match. It is unfortunate that both are "streams".

Comment: Streams aren't really designed for this, which is why you find it "very difficult to implement". You can instead implement an infinite `InputStream` that produces a bunch of characters, and have a `Scanner` read from it.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't explain my intention clearly. What I'm thinking is to create an infinite stream of random charactors and see when I can encounter the word that I specify. It's like an experiment. java.util.stream api is very handy to produce a stream of infinite random charactors, but seems difficult to do the matching. InputStream seems even more impractical. It only accepts inputs from files, urls and user console.Infinity is not possible. What should I do? Thanks for sharing your wisdom.